# sys.dm_db_file_space_usage not returning correct values in SQL 2019

Tags: sql-server, dmv, sql-server-2019

Scripts I use for database space metrics on our SQL Server do not return the correct values for ***allocated_extent_page_count*** and ***unallocated_extent_page_count*** from ***sys.dm_db_file_space_usage*** when run against our SQL Server 2019 (RTM - 15.0.2000.5 (X64) Developer Edition (64-bit))
) instances.

They work correctly with SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU5 - 13.0.5264.1 (X64) Developer Edition) and SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU12 - 14.0.3045.24 (X64)   Developer Edition (64-bit)).

I first noticed this on databases where we had a large partitioned table that used VARCHAR(MAX) columns with large strings so I thought it may have been related to partition maintenance or LOB_DATA allocation units being ignored but I've stripped the test script down to the below and it is still a problem.

```
USE [master]
GO

IF DB_ID('testdmv') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    DROP DATABASE [TestDmv];
END

GO

CREATE DATABASE [TestDmv] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'TestDmv', FILENAME = N'D:\TestDmv.mdf' , SIZE = 5120MB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024MB )
 LOG ON ( NAME = N'TestDmv_log', FILENAME = N'D:\TestDmv_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024MB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 1024MB )
 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = DATABASE_DEFAULT

GO

IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
    EXEC [TestDmv].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'disable'
end
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF;
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET ARITHABORT OFF; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT GLOBAL; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET  DISABLE_BROKER; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET  MULTI_USER; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM;  
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET DB_CHAINING OFF; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET FILESTREAM( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = OFF );
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 60 SECONDS; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET DELAYED_DURABILITY = DISABLED; 
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET QUERY_STORE = OFF;
ALTER DATABASE [TestDmv] SET READ_WRITE; 
GO


USE [TestDmv]
GO
---------------------------------------------

SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO

GO
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetSpaceComparison
AS
SELECT  'FileProperty'                                                              AS [MetricSource],
        SUM(CAST(DF.size / 128.0 AS Dec(9,1)))                                      AS [SizeMB],
        SUM(CAST(FILEPROPERTY(df.name, 'SpaceUsed') / 128.0 AS Dec(9,1)))           AS [UsedMB],
        SUM(CAST((df.size - FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed')) / 128.0 AS Dec(9,1)))  AS [FreeMB]
FROM    TestDmv.sys.database_files AS df
WHERE   df.type_desc = 'ROWS'
GROUP   BY df.type_desc

UNION ALL

SELECT  'dmv'                                                               AS [MetricSource],
        SUM(CAST(total_page_count * 8 / 1024.0 AS Dec(9,1)))                AS [SizeMB],
        SUM(CAST(allocated_extent_page_count  * 8 / 1024.0 AS Dec(9,1)))    AS [UsedMB],
        SUM(CAST(unallocated_extent_page_count  * 8 / 1024.0 AS Dec(9,1)))  AS [FreeMB]
FROM    TestDmv.sys.dm_db_file_space_usage 
ORDER BY [MetricSource]
GO


SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [EntryTime] [datetime2](2) NOT NULL,
    [BigCol1] [varchar](4000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [BigCol2] [varchar](4000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, /* OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF, */ DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Test] SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = AUTO)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Test_EntryTime] ON [dbo].[Test]
(   [EntryTime] ASC,
    [Id] ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, /*OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF, */ DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[TestId]  AS [bigint]
 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE -9223372036854775808  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807  CACHE  1000 
GO

PRINT '------DB Space Status before data load------'

EXEC dbo.GetSpaceComparison;

GO
SET NOCOUNT ON ;

DECLARE @SQL                VARCHAR(MAX),
        @i                  INT = 0,
        @Id                 BIGINT,
        @ServerUTCDatetime  DATETIME2(2);

DECLARE @c1 VARCHAR(4000)= '',
        @c2 VARCHAR(4000)= ''
WHILE LEN(@C1) < 4000
BEGIN
    SET @C1 += CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(36))
END

WHILE LEN(@C2) < 4000
BEGIN
    SET @C2 += CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(36))
END



SET @i = 0
WHILE @i <100000
BEGIN
    SET @i += 1

    SET @Id = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.TestId;
    SET @ServerUTCDatetime = SYSUTCDATETIME();

    INSERT INTO dbo.Test (Id, EntryTime, BigCol1, BigCol2)
    VALUES (@Id, @ServerUTCDatetime, @C1, @C2)

END

CHECKPOINT;

PRINT '
------DB Space Status after initial data load------'

EXEC dbo.GetSpaceComparison;


EXEC sp_spaceused;
SELECT  type_desc, 
        CAST(SUM(total_pages) * 8 / 1024.0 AS DEC(9, 1)) AS [total_mb], 
        CAST(SUM(used_pages) * 8 / 1024.0 AS DEC(9, 1)) AS [used_mb],
        CAST(SUM(data_pages) * 8 / 1024.0 AS DEC(9, 1)) AS [data_mb]
FROM sys.allocation_units
GROUP BY type_desc
ORDER BY type_desc
```

Comment: That's a lot of script. Could you reduce this to (a) a table that produces the problem and (b) the query that shows the wrong value(s) and (c) what you believe those values should be and why?

Comment: Also, [please don't run RTM](https://sqlperformance.com/latest-builds/sql-server-2019). Right now, you're missing over 200 fixes.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand, from initial testing it seems that SQL 2019 CU2 has fixed the problem. I could not see any mention of the dmv in the CU notes but something must have been changed.
I included the relatively long script as the table creation and dmv query alone do not indicate any problem by themselves and I needed the other code to reproduce the issue. I agree I could have still made it more concise though but wanted to provide all the DB settings in case they were relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Applying SQL 2019 CU2, as suggested by Aaron Bertrand, has fixed the issue and now sys.dm_db_file_space_usage return the correct values for allocated_extent_page_count and unallocated_extent_page_count.